# CodeIgniter 3.1.2 having 404 error?

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, localhost, http-status-code-404

I currently have a partially developed web application for my Computing coursework. I have been using CodeIgniter 3.1.2 at college using http://localhost/ as the hostname to view the project. I have made a copy of the entire folder that I was working within (called htdocs) so as to continue at home. I have managed to get apache2 installed on my laptop (Ubuntu 16.04) and have also installed php7.0. I have managed to configure these in a manner that means that if I have a freshly unzipped CodeIgniter package, I can see the default welcome screen ([see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjIDu.png)). This folder is located at:

`/var/www/html/CodeIgniter-3.1.2`

Inside of this directory are the things you expect to see in CodeIgniter (the application directory, the index.php file, etc.). I now obviously wish to continue from where I left off from college so I take the contents of htdocs (which has all the same directories and files in as a default, fresh CodeIgniter install) paste them inside of

`/var/www/html/CodeIgniter-3.1.2`.

My understanding is that this should just overwrite the default files with the ones I have been using at college (which works fine), but instead, I am receiving a 404 error. Why is this?

**Here is htaccess**

```
<IfModule authz_core_module>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
```

Although I have not changed this since the day I started. I can and will add any extra information if requested, thanks.

Comment: That htaccess looks like the one from application folder. Don't touch that one.

Comment: If you need to put a new htaccess put it in main directory https://github.com/wolfgang1983/htaccess_for_codeigniter

Comment: @wolfgang1983 I'm sorry I'm not too sure what you mean. I'm fairly new to all this, so am unsure as to what .htaccess actually does. Considering I've been working at college, restrictions have meant that I can't even view that file, let alone change it. What, if any, htaccess file are you suggesting I use? And in the main directory of what? Sorry for being a bit useless here!